# How to display Modal Popup on home when user login to salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have created LWC Modal popup which is currently displayed on Home Page when home page gets loaded. I have to display Popup when user login to salesforce and once it came on home page.
If user reload the home page after login popup should not be displayed. (It should be displayed at first time after login to salesforce)

below are the LWC Popup files and my apex class

HTML:

```
<template>

    <template if:true={isModalOpen}>
        <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-backdrop">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Close this window" size="large" variant="bare-inverse" onclick={closeModal} class="slds-modal__close">
                    </lightning-button-icon>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Pending Opportunity Alerts</h2>
                </header>
                
                <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id">
                    <p><b> &nbsp; Hello!...
                    </b></p>
                    <p><b> &nbsp; You have some pendings opportunities...Please work on it before month end.
                    </b></p>
                    <p><b> &nbsp; For more detials see the reports.
                    </b></p>
                </div>
                
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={navigateToReport} title="View Report">View Report</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={submitDetails} title="Close">Close</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    </template>

 </template>
```

JS file:

```
import { LightningElement, track ,wire} from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import getCount from '@salesforce/apex/PendingOppCount.getCount';

export default class POPUP extends NavigationMixin (LightningElement) {

    @track isModalOpen = false;
    @track userId = Id;

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.getCount();
        console.log('Currently Logged in Useer ID:-',this.userId);

    }

    openModal() 
    {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
        
    }

    closeModal() {
        
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }
    submitDetails() {
        
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }

    getCount(){
        console.log('Inside getCount');
        getCount({CurrUserId: this.userId}) 
        .then(result => {
            //console.log('Inside getCount');
            this.data = result;
            console.log('Inside getCount',this.data);
            this.error = undefined;
            if(this.data > 0){
                console.log('Inside openModal');
                this.openModal();
            }else{
                console.log('Inside closeModal');
                this.closeModal();
            }
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Inside error',this.error);
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;
        });
    }

    navigateToReport() {
        const config = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: '/lightning/r/Report/00O5g00000GmtuKEAR/view?queryScope=userFolders'
            }
        };
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](config);
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets> 
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Apex Class:

```
public without sharing class PendingOppCount 
{
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static string getCount(String CurrUserId)
    {
        System.debug('Currently loggend in User ID :'+CurrUserId);
        string OppCount;
        List <Opportunity> opplst = [SELECT Id,Name from Opportunity WHERE Pending_Opp__c = TRUE AND OwnerId =: CurrUserId]; 
        System.debug('Pending Opp :'+opplst);
        
        if(opplst.size()>0)
        {
            OppCount = string.valueOf(opplst.size());
            System.debug('OppCount '+OppCount);
        }
        return OppCount;
    }
}
```

Please provide solution in lwc only

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no special "just logged in" parameter you can use. Maybe you could try querying the user's last login date and deciding whether to show/hide it if it's same second or say "in last 5 seconds"? And if it's an older session - don't query opportunities, return 0?

You're doing it wrong. User can keep their session alive for hours, days even - and will never see the popup again? User can craft a "deep link" to say a report (for example a bookmark), SF will redirect them to login page and on success dutifully jump to that report, bypassing home page.

Read up about [login flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_login_flow_examples.htm&type=5)